# How can i work with separate elements in a list of objects?

Tags: python, list, object

So, i have a huge list of objects which contains: Level Of Difficulty, Math Expression, Result. I'm trying to build a game and want to print the expression and check the result, but i don't know how to print a separate element.
What my list looks like:
3, s, 520 + 370, 890
I want to print only the expression:
Something like: print(list, key=lambda x: x.nivel)
But only one of the elements of the list e one object(nivel in this case)

Code:

```
class Expressao(object):

    def __init__(self, nivel, tipo, expressao, resposta):
        self.nivel = nivel
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.expressao = expressao
        self.resposta = resposta

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.nivel + ", " + self.tipo + ", " + self.expressao + ", " + self.resposta`

class FonteDeExpressoes(object):
    import csv
    def lista (self):
        expressoes = []
        with open('exp.txt') as f:
            for line in f:
                row = line.split('\t')
                exp = Expressao(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])
                expressoes.append(exp)
        #print expressoes
        return expressoes
```

Comment: Please [edit] to show a [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried anything?Post sample of your codes and we'll try to help you..The SO community can't figure out what you are trying to accomplish without that part of your code that you need help with..

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I get this error:
TypeError: 'Expressao' object does not support indexing

Comment: Please add your traceback and show what exactly you're doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the list `expressoes`, you can get the attributes of the contained class instances using `map` or a *list comprehension*:

```
list_of_nivels = map(lambda x: x.nivel, expressoes)
```

In Python 3.x, you'll need to call `list` on `map` to return a list

And with a comprehension:

```
list_of_nivels = [expressao.nivel for expressao in expressoes]
```

---

To return more than one attribute from every instance in the list, you can use [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
import operator

nivels_and_resposta = [operator.attrgetter('nivel', 'resposta')(x) for x in expressoes]
```

Comment: This solves my problem! But my lists return something like this: ('3', '82\r\n') I understand \n for the newline but not the \r.

Comment: @AlexandrePedrecal That's a carriage return. Some systems usually specify the EOL character as `'\r\n'`